# How to add calendar event to database that repeats every x day/week?

Tags: mysql, database, date, database-design

For a user management software I try to implement a feature, where employees can provide their availabilities at a specific location.

I got a form:

```
Location   [> LOC1; LOC2, LOC3]
Start      [YYYY-MM-DD] [HH:ii]
End        [YYYY-MM-DD] [HH:ii]
Full day   [X]
Frequence  [> ONCE; EVERY MONDAY; EVERY 2ND WEEK]
```

This goes to the follow database table scheme:

```
eid | lid | start | end | allay | frequence
```

Where frequence is `NULL` for once, `1` for every day of the week provided by start value, and `2` for every 2. week.

With that I have the following logic:
[image: Possible cases]

Where Y is always greater than X (both include date and time).

As far as I can think of, this is covering all possible cases. Logically I can use that to query a presence, but I am struggling with the dates, that are available in infinity. My logic is, if start and end date are the same, and frequence is not null, then this row will be available always and in infinity.

E.g. employee is available from `2022-03-31 10:00:00` to `2022-03-31 18:00:00`, allday 0, frequence 1, then he is available every Thursday between 10am and 6pm.

So far, so good, so logic, but when I now want to use that, I am struggling, and I want to ask you experts, if this is the right way to implement that.

Issues I see:

- Query: Is an employee available at a specific date / time? For the infinity cases, I don't know hot to query that.
- If there is a frequent rule in place, and I add another rule that overwrites the same rule, I don't know how to avoid duplicates.

E.g.:

- `2022-03-31 10:00:00` `2022-03-31 18:00:00` `0` `1`
- `2022-04-14 17:00:00` `2022-04-17 20:00:00` `0` `null`
- In consequence at 2022-04-14 the employee is available from 10am to 8pm.

And last issue I see:
If I want to build a calendar that shows a specific month (e.g. October 22) and I want all availabilities in that month, how can I get every single date and time value for every single day in that month for rows like:

- `2022-03-31 10:00:00` `2022-03-31 18:00:00` `0` `1`
- `2022-03-31 00:00:00` `2022-12-31 00:00:00` `1` `2`

As my database design is bad maybe, I don't see a value in adding a mysql fiddle with some sample data. But anyhow if you wish to see that, let me know, and I'll update my question.

What I'd prefer maybe, is, to add a row for every day where an employee is available. This would be easier and more intuitive and I can handle to logic once, when I add an availability, but how would I handle infinite dates there? I could assume that the app will not be used longer than 20y and add every date in the next 20 years?!

Comment: Search not for "event calendar table" but for "schedule table". AFAIR there was some threads about this...

Comment: Thank you. I found this, what is kinda cool. I did not know, that I can build procedures. With this it is very easy, to add a range of dates, but this is know bringing light into my struggle with infinity: https://gist.github.com/bryhal/4129042

Comment: @Akina When I search mysql schedule table I found many articles related the the event scheduler but this seems not to be the right solution for me, as this is a kind of cronjob for mysql

Comment: What is the difference? This is a schedule. And no difference what engine uses it - CRON or MySQL.

Comment: @Akina how does this help me? This will automatically add events for me. But for what reason? Isn't one row per event enough? I don't understand